# How to debug modbus rtu address space problems?

Tags: memory, addressing, modbus

I have an "**Ewon Flexy server**" and an "**IMO SD1 Inverter**" connected via Modbus RTU RS485.

I can change some of the parameters with Flexy interface and observe the change in the inverter, but I have no idea how to convert the address in the inverter manual to Ewon Flexy format.

For instance, the SD1 inverter's p00.01 maps to Flexy's input register 40002. I can read and write this and the values I read and write are the same as shown in the inverter manual terminal. The address 40002 I found out by accident.

I don't understand the format given by the inverter manual and the addresses given there don't work.

For instance, inverter address 2001H is start. Ewon Flexy expects something between 40000 to 49999. (Should I try something like 42001?)

How can debug what is wrong and find correct addresses?

Comment: First up, get the modbus standard and understand the different address types. This will explain the 40000 class of address. Different manufacturers can express the addresses differently which is the source of your confusion. Also there’s numbering from 0 or 1 which further confuses. The address 40000… is a decimal number, you can’t slap a hex number on without conversion. 2001H is 8193 decimal, so the address might be 408193.

Comment: Thanks, so I am in the right track... I found this example: **006B: The address of the first register (40108-40001 = 107 = 6B hex)** which in my case means that 2001 hex = X - 40001 or X = 8193 + 40001 = 48194 in decimal. This should be the correct number? Now the inverter manufacturer has made some "enable modbus control" flags that need to be enabled for this to work and if this does not work its the flags (not the address) that are the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The start-stop input register address is given in hex: 2000H. This corresponds to 8192 decimal.

In the modbus standard these are exposed between 40001 - 49999.

The address to write start-stop command in modbus is then 48193.

In other words add the hex address as decimal to 40001 => 40001 + 8192 = 48193.

Specific to this case, inverter parameters that enable modbus are p00.01 = 2 and p09.02 = 4 (note! p09.02, not p00.02). These are set manually from the terminal.